# How to sum up all the goals scored by the players

Tags: mysql

I would like to ask how I can sum up all the goals scored by the players in the last 7 days.
The name of the table is **player_games**, the field that contains the date on which the game was played is **game_played.**

I tried summing the scores but I receive 0 as result for scores. The last week where is not included.

```
SELECT player_id as playerID, SUM('scores') as scores 
FROM `player_games` 
GROUP BY player_id 
ORDER BY SUM('scores') DESC
```

Comment: So your actual question is "how to sum".

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You're summing a string. The string 'scores' evaluates to zero. And the sum of those zeros is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT player_id as playerID, SUM(scores) as scores 
FROM `player_games` 
 WHERE game_played >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
GROUP BY player_id 
ORDER BY scores DESC
```

Comment: Thanks to all for the help. This is the solution that matches my needs.

Comment: You sure? @user10087184 `player_id >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY` is doing the date check on the wrong column.. You said `game_played.` was the correct date column right? @SebastianBrosch answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following using [`DATE_SUB`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) and [`CURDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate):

```
SELECT player_id AS playerID, SUM(scores) AS scores 
FROM player_games
WHERE game_played BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY player_id 
ORDER BY SUM(scores) DESC
```

---

You can also use the date calculation directly on the `WHERE` condition without using [`DATE_SUB`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub):

```
SELECT player_id AS playerID, SUM(scores) AS scores 
FROM player_games
WHERE game_played BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY player_id 
ORDER BY SUM(scores) DESC
```

Comment: Topicstarter also notice that MySQL supports direct dates calculation with `INTERVAL` keyword something like this is also valid MySQL code `game_played  BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND CURDATE()`

Comment: @RaymondNijland It doesn't actually; it just quietly rewrites it when executing.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the INTERVAL:

```
SELECT SUM(goals) FROM PLAYER_GAMES WHERE GAME_PLAYED >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY;
```

EDIT:

Don't sum a string (i.e., don't use quotes).

Answer (score -1):

The following should work
SELECT c.name, SUM(g.goals)
FROM Countries as c
RIGHT JOIN Goals as g ON c.id = g.country_id
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
ORDER BY c.name ASC

Comment: This doesn't address the "last seven days" part of the question.